# MAVEN ошибка после установки плагина STS

Tags: java, maven

После того как установил в Eclipse плагин STS, maven во всех проектах в IDE начал выдавать мне следующею ошибку: 
- maven configuration problems:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org   pom.xml /caferacer  line 1  Maven Configuration Problem
```

- maven java ee conf problems:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   An error occurred while filtering resources caferacer       line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration Problem

-maven problems:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /caferacer  line 426    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7108536/5694145

Comment: @enzo помогло, спасбио

Comment: @enzo, как насчет оформить ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Удалите все временные файлы, которые остаются в локальном репозитории Maven при неудачной загрузке артифакта (имеют расширение `.lastUpdated`):

**Linux:**

```
find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

**Windows:**

Из командной строки:

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

Или:

- зайти в локальный репозиторий `%userprofile%\.m2` через Проводник;
- выполнить поиск по расширению файла `.lastUpdated`;
- выделить и удалить результаты поиска;

---

**2)** Выполните принудительное обновление проекта: `ALT + F5` или `Maven > Update Project` в контекстном меню проекта (перед обновлением убедитесь, что активна опция "Update Dependencies").

**Источник:** [StackOverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108536/5694145)